# A Stack Overflow for Stack Overflow

Tags: vb.net, types, recursion

I was wondering if I could have the parent class instantiate an object of a child class, without going into an infinite recursion.

Consider this example:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim _baseFruit As New Fruit
        _baseFruit.Write()

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Fruit
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property BaseType As String
    Public Property FruitType As New Apple

    Sub New()
        Type = "Fruit"
        BaseType = "N/A"
    End Sub

    Public Sub Write()
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} BaseType: {1} FruitType: {2} ", Type, BaseType, FruitType.Type)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Apple
    Inherits Fruit

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Type = "Apple"
    End Sub
End Class
```

As soon as an Apple is instantiated, it's entering the infinite recursion.

Is it incorrect to say this is impossible, that is to have a child referenced in the parent which is also the base ?

EDIT: From the answer below I have updated the code, lo and behold, it works.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim _baseFruit As New Fruit
        Dim _apple As New Apple

        _baseFruit.Write(_apple)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Fruit
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property BaseType As String
    Public Property FruitChildInstance As Apple

    Sub New()
        Type = "Fruit"
        BaseType = "N/A"
    End Sub

    Public Sub Write(ByVal fruit As Apple)
        FruitChildInstance = fruit
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} BaseType: {1} FruitType: {2} ", Type, BaseType, FruitChildInstance.Type)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Apple
    Inherits Fruit

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Type = "Apple"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be called an "infinite type".  It doesn't have to be a problem if you allow the member variable to be left empty.

Without looking at the actual meaning of this code, you could say this:

Dictating that the `FruitType` member has to be an `Apple` instance results in an infinite amount of objects nesting.  Leaving it uninitialized (`Dim FruitType as Fruit`) would cause no problem at all.

Now when you *do* take the semantic into account:

You're mixing the "Type" concept with the "Instance" concept: a `Fruit` instance has-a type (e.g. the *class* `Apple`), but it's quite strange to let it have-a Fruit member, too.

If you would have modeled this as a class `FruitType`, where a `Fruit` has a member dimensioned `FruitType`, the infinite recursion wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Very eloquent and easy to understand. I will update the class to account for this. Of course I would argue that if you are doing this you may need to rethink your implementation but never the less a great example of the pitfalls of bad design.